# Which home/small business routers allow to define exceptions in QoS?

Tags: router, networking

I have this configuration:

```
[home network] -> [router] -> [ISP router] -> (Internet)
                                          |-> private sites in 10.0.0.0/8 network
```

ISP route private addresses to distinct private/corporate sites (i.e. through VPN maked by ISP).

ISP router do very basic throttling (based on contract) which even kills any VoIP when someone's Windows download updates. Traffic to private sites is not throttled at all.

Home router need to have QoS configuration which throttle up&down to avoid congestion directed to Internet, but also need to **not** throttle traffic to selected destinations.

Thus question is: Which home/small business routers<sup>1</sup> (models) allows to exclude some destinations from QoS?

I tried to check features lists for Ubiquity, Microtek, Netgear, D-Link, TP-Link and many others, but can't find so precise requirement.

Current ISP contract defines downlink 300 and uplink 30 Mbps, but could change to 600/60 in future.

PS. As router i mean new (with warranty) and ready-to-fire solution, not homebrew with software like OPNSense or pfSense + buy-somewhere hardware.

PPS. QoS need to support down and up speed without slowing it down.

PPPS. QoS may be very basic, only need to avoid congestion (slowing down all traffic by one or more devices) on Internet traffic and allow to send/receive *fully without QoS* to some destinations.
*Fully without QoS* may be second QoS rule if router allows that.

<sup>1</sup> Home/small business router means for me prices to about $300.